# Running command on server, but have the server read/write local files

Tags: networking, ssh, io

Is it possible to have a remote machine run a command, but redirect all reads and writes to a local machine.

Example:
I have a bunch of scripts in folder 'project'. When 'make simulate' is run in 'project' a heavy simulation is run according to some input files and when done, output files are saved in the same folder. All this happens on my laptop, which is limited by battery and isn't as high-end as my desktop. Is there a way to have the simulation run on the desktop (for example via ssh) without going through the hassle of first copying the folder to the desktop, run the simulation there and then copy it all back? All relevant programs must of course be installed on the desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the easiest solution is to "see" the local file system (or a part of it) on the server. For instance, you can use [SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS).

Comment: Yes `sshfs` need no special software on the server end, just sshd (in your case your laptop). And `sshfs` on the other end.